# Receiving a Bad Request error when creating webhook

Tags: surveymonkey

When I try to send in a POST to create a new webhook I receive a bad request error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes",
        "message": "URL https://ws.nxturn.com/NXT_survey_response did not return a success status code.",
        "id": "1000",
        "name": "Bad Request",
        "http_status_code": 400
    }
}
```

However, when I try to send a HEAD to my server I receive a 200 response back as expected. I am not sure how I can troubleshoot this?

Has anyone else resolved this issue?

Answer (score -1):

That URL does not support HTTPS